# how do i troubleshoot a substantial AC volatge neutral to ground?

Tags: electrical, grounding, voltage

I've been having some problems with my computers at home. Today I decided to check voltage from the receptacles. I have 120VAC hot to Neutral, as I would expect, but then I have 50VAC Hot to GND, and Neutral to GND. I had a heat pump installed a month ago, Im not sure if that is part of the issue, the guys who installed it, were the last people in my panel. I have also noticed a higher than normal electrical bill for the past few months.

I tried unplugging nearly all the devices (not the heat pump), but I still observe the stray 50VAC. It seems to fluctuate between 20-50VAC.  Im not sure how to trace out what is causing the issue, I get the 50VAC nuetral to gnd at every receptacle in the house.

Comment: Can you upload a picture of your circuit breaker panel?

Comment: I can do that tomorow... or later today, im pretty tired right now

Comment: Yes, can you post a photo of the breaker panel?  Also, do you measure similar readings at various outlets on different circuits, or just on this one circuit/receptacle?

Answer (score 2):

Could be a dangerous condition!  You may have lost the neutral or partially lifted in the heat pump,  and it it returning the current over the ground energizing the whole house ground.  One possibility is the new heat pump needed 4 wires with 240 and 120 loads and the installer used the ground as neutral... Just a wild guess...  How many wires in your panel box run to the heat Pump?

Prob a good idea to get an electrician in especially if it's effecting your electronics already.

Comment: The heat pump itself typically wouldn't have a neutral connection

Answer (score 0):

What it seems like you're system ( electrical service) is not grounded. To verify this, at the panel take a voltage reading from the hot buss to the neutral buss and from the neural buss to the grounding buss. If your voltage reading is still 50 volts on both reading, then your system (service) is not grounded. If your reading is, hot to neutral is 120V and if neutral to ground is zero or close to then your system is grounded and your problem is in your circuit you have lost the grounded conductor.